# Typecasting and foreach

Tags: c#

I was curious if this procedure im doing could be archieved in a much more elegant and cleaner manner?

```
        foreach (MediaTitle item in mediaTitleCollection)
        {
            if (item is FilmMedia)
            {
                FilmMedia tempItem = (FilmMedia) item;
                sum += tempItem.Playtime;
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var sum = mediaTitleCollection.OfType<FilmMedia>().Sum(x => x.Playtime);
```

Comment: I like that this answer skips the unnecessary select transformation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) for the type check and cast (filtering to only elements of type `FilmMedia`) and then just calculate the sum based on the `PlayTime` property:

```
sum = mediaTitleCollection.OfType<FilmMedia>()
                          .Select(x=> x.Playtime)
                          .Sum();
```

Comment: should work fine based on your original code - are you using it exactly as is?

Comment: `Aggregate()` will always work but mostly the syntax is too general, I try to avoid it when I can - the better alternative in this case would be @Jason's solution to directly calculate the sum by property - I didn't want to update my answer to do this though since he had it first.

Answer (score 4):

Non-LINQ:

```
    foreach (MediaTitle item in mediaTitleCollection)
    {
        FilmMedia tempItem = item as FilmMedia;
        if (tempItem != null)
        {
            sum += tempItem.Playtime;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this isn't much different than the original code, but I removed the double-cast that was happening.

Comment: A very abstract question. But is there any performance issues going for a Non-LINQ method?

Comment: @JavaCake: Not any that matter unless this is an **extremely** performance critical section of your application. That seems unlikely to be the case.

Comment: The performance difference between the two should be negligible if even measurable. If you have .NET 3.5 or later at your disposal, definitely go with one of the LINQ solutions. The readability alone is worth it. Jason's answer got my vote for that very reason.

Comment: Im going with Jasons aswell! Its very neat.